# Advantage of declaring to-be-overridden member methods in an interface

Tags: c#, interface

Hello my fellow developers,

I am currently working on migrating several classes to a new project as part of a redesign task.
The classes that are being migrated to the new solution are being replaced by interfaces in the existing project as follows:

EXISTING PROJECT --> New Interface 
NEW PROJECT      --> Existing just-migrated class implementing the new interface

Due to the current inheritance, the classes already override methods from other interfaces.

Now my question is: Since the interfaces that I am implementing are in the middle, is there any advantage on declaring member methods in the new interface that are going to be anyway overridden by the class rather than obligate the class to actually implement them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> is there any advantage on declaring member methods in the new interface that are going to be anyway overridden by the class rather than obligate the class to actually implement them?

A key advantage of using interfaces is that code can work with the interface, rather than a concrete implementation of a class.  If you do not have `OverriddenMethod()` in the interface, the following will not work

```
ISomething myInterface = new MyConcreteClass();
myInterface.OverriddenMethod();
```

Anything that the outside world uses to work with the class should be exposed as part of the interface.